# How to load library within another library?

Tags: php, codeigniter

there is a similar question to this from a couple years ago, but I didn't quite understand the answer ([link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281575/code-igniter-load-library-from-within-library))

My problem is the following: I've created a library that I'm calling from a controller, and within that library I'm using the image manipulation functions that CodeIgniter offers. But that's obviously a library. From a controller there's no problem: `$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);` the $config variable has of course the parameters to create the image. The question is: How can I call that library (and pass the $config array) from within another library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how you do it in helpers and other libraries:

```
$ci =& get_instance();

$config = array(
    //...
);
$ci->load->library('image_lib', $config);

$ci->image_lib->whatever();
```

What you do here is get the instance of the CodeIgniter singleton object and work with it, as libraries can't use `$this` because `$this` used in libraries points at themselves. Simply do all your usual things, but using `$ci->` instead of `$this->`

Answer (score 1):

Your **$this** var will have lost it's CodeIgniter resources, to use the CodeIgniter Resources you'll have to create another instance of it get_instance();

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

Now you can use $CI as you would $this

You can read more about it here under "Utilizing CodeIgniter Resources within Your Library" http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html